# ForwardIterator combined with multiple bind's is iterating too fast

Tags: c++, stl

i want to iterate over a `vector` of `int`s and remove all even numbers.

Example:

```
std::vector<int> v = {5,2,9,3,8}

auto it = std::remove_if(v.begin(),v.end(), 
    std::bind(std::bind(std::equal_to<int>(),_1,0),
    std::bind(std::modulus<int>(),_1,2)));
```

The expected result should be {5,9,3}
But it is {5,8,9,3,8}

I think the Iterator is already at the end before performing all functions in bind and remove.

I know how to solve it differently but i want to know how to use the nested form and how it works with iterators

Comment: Not an answer, but this would be much easier to read as a lambda instead of `std::bind` expressions. Lambdas are available since C++11.

Comment: Use lambdas. `bind` inside `bind` [behaves counterintuitively](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) (look for mention of `std::is_bind_expression`)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik do u have a hint how to structure it as a lambda? Have not used them often yet

Comment: `auto it = std::remove_if(..., [](int val) { return val % 2 == 0; });`

Comment: What "result"? `it` is one iterator. Be less vague.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Please, stop answering in comments. We are unable to peer review your contributions. Hopefully that is not your deliberate intention

Comment: i'd personally like to see an answer explaining what the bind-form is actually doing, as written. responses about how to solve it another way (e.g. with lambdas) _aren't_ answers to the question and, imo, _should_ be in comments.

Comment: @RobStarling, OP seems to be interested in how to do it with a lambda.  Read the comments.

Comment: @SidS, i read that as an aside for comment-land. The question still says "I know how to solve it differently but i want to know how to use the nested form and how it works with iterators".

Comment: it's also a more interesting question this way. "How do i use a lambda?" should probably be closed as a dup or insufficiently-researched.

Answer (score 2):

In VS2015, your code leaves `v` containing {5, 9, 3, 3, 8}.

`std::remove_if()` returns an iterator to the first unused element in the `vector`, use that to truncate the `vector` :

```
v.erase(it, v.end());
```

After that, `v` contains {5, 9, 3}

---

On a side note, if you want to use a lambda instead of `bind` you can do it like this:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 5, 2, 9, 3, 8 };
auto it = std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int val) { return val % 2 == 0; });
v.erase(it, v.end());
```

Comment: Btw, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove has some excellent comments about all of this.

Comment: As an additional side-note, the comment "The similarly-named container member functions list::remove, list::remove_if, forward_list::remove, and forward_list::remove_if erase the removed elements." is interesting.

Comment: Also, you don't _have_ to truncate the vector if you remember to stop at `it` instead of `v.end()`. Something to remember if you're just _using_ the results once and gonna let the whole vector get destroyed.

Comment: You might want to edit the "In VS2015, your code leaves v containing {5, 9, 3, 3, 8}." part to note that the elements after `it` are in an undefined state as some of them were `move`d into the `[v.begin(), it)` range.